# best way to combine two tables that have same columns and different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem finding the best way to combine two of my tables in sql.
i have 2 user-feature tables like below with the same columns but different values:
this 2 table represent user-feature profile of a user , but generate from different sources what i need is to combine this to a single user-feature table and we dont know if the data for user(i) from table1 is more authentic or from table2. 
 what do you think is the best way to combine this 2 table? 
 for example should i use mean value or max-min or is there a better way?

```
Table1:

user   feature1    feature2
 A        2          8
 B        4          3
 C        1          6
```

Table2:

```
user   feature1    feature2
 A        3          6
 B        2          4
 C        4          8
```

Comment: What is the expected output? _More authentic_ is not very useful metric to judge which value should you choose.

Comment: expected output should be like a user-feature table with feature1 & feature2 columns problem is how should i combine values for each user? these values are weight assign to each feature of a user by different sources and i need to combine it to one table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i'm using mysql

Answer (score 1):

simply use join query this is the best way when you are having at least one same column in both table & in these tables you have user column as identity

```
select 
a.user, a.feature1 as FeatureA, b.feature1 as FeatureB 
from table1 a join table2 b 
on a.user=b.user;
```

Comment: no i need table3 to have feature1 and feature2 columns like table 1&2 i need to merge the values for each user for example by using the mean value.

Comment: then create a table with this result like if you are using mssql then use into table3 before from and if you are using mysql then use create table table3 as (this syntex);

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to look at the code that uses these tables and see how it differs

Maybe one table isn't used any more

Maybe one table is for setting user interface features and other is for setting data processing features (in which case make one table called features with 4 columns called uiFeature1, uiFeature2, dpFeatire1, dpFeature2

Essentially here you have asked a question that no one on the internet can answe for you; you're going to have to do the research yourself

Comment: yes your right i should do research i just want to know what are the best ways so that i can do comparison between them

Comment: That's sort of not what you aske, but you can do comparison with your eyeballs. Only you can work out which feature table is more relevant by looking at how they are used. Maybe it will turn out you need to take the max or average value from each table. If so you can return here for help with the query, but we offer advice on questions like "how do I go from two tables and take the max value from column 1 to make a single table with all the max values" we don't answe questions like "which of the two cheeses in my lunchbox is nicer?"